# list files based on characters in a dataframe (partial name matching)

Tags: r, subset

I have a directory containing multiple files. The filenames are the same format and look like this:

```
mar_1999_cloglog.asc
mar_2000_cloglog.asc
mar_2001_cloglog.asc
```

etc.

The first part of the filename refers to the month (in this case March), the second the year (1999, 2000 etc).

I also have a single-column dataframe with each row containing a year:

```
'data.frame':   11 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ yrlst: int  1998 2001 2002 2003 2004 2006 2009 2010 2011 2013
```

I'm trying to list the files in the directory whose year is found in dataframe. I created a list of files in the directory, then converted the dataframe into a vector (`dfvector`), and then use grep to pattern match, but the resulting list is empty:

```
dirlst <- list.files(paste0("filepath", pattern = "cloglog", recursive = FALSE, full.names = TRUE) 
test <- grep(list.files(dirlst), pattern = dfvector, value = TRUE)
```

I've tried a couple of other variations, but no luck. Can anyone help with this? I am sure it is pretty easy, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `dirlst` already contains a `list.files`, and inside the `grep` you again apply `list.files(dirlst)`; is that intended?

Comment: @Bas good point - I did not need to `list.files` twice... I'm not sure why I did that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even a much better way.

```
list_dir <- c("1900.asc", "1901.asc", "1902.asc", "1903.asc", "1904.asc","1905.asc","1906.asc")
years <- c("1901","1904")
select_files <- list_dir[grepl(paste(years, collapse= "|"), list_dir)]
```

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Happy to help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This one involves a small loop.

I created a sample dataset for this problem.
**a** is same as the list.files(filepath, patter=".asc")
**b** is same as the dataframe of list of years.

```
a <- c("1900.asc", "1901.asc", "1902.asc", "1903.asc", "1904.asc","1905.asc","1906.asc")
b <- c("1901","1904")    
x <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(b)){
      
y <- a[grepl(b[i], a)]
x <- union(x, y)
  
}
x
```

The desired output is obtained as a character vector.